# What do you call a cover for outdoor main sewage cleanout and where can I find one?

Tags: cleanout

I am looking for something like this:

[image]

It is for my home after adding a new clean out. Here is what it looks like:

[image]

I searched the web high and low but I can't seem to find where to buy it. Maybe because I don't even know what it is called. Can someone help?

Answer (score 3):

They're called **valve boxes**, but may also be called **cleanout boxes** or **monument boxes** though that seems rare for the residential application, and should be available at most any home center or home-improvement-related store.

[image: Valve box]

---

Image taken from Home Depot, and is used as an example only

Comment: Thanks. Would there be one that says "CLEAN OUT" on the cover? I wonder if there is special requirements for covering clean outs?

Comment: @someuser edited to add they may also be called cleanout boxes or monument boxes, which should help your search.

Comment: I found some document about requirement and it seems the city want "Christy Box F-8 or equivalent". It is made of concrete and it is expensive. I am not sure what alternative is considered equivalent but it does not look like the one pictured would cut it.

Comment: Where I live no one uses valve boxes to hide or protect the sanitary sewer clean-outs though I think this would be a good idea to protect it from lawn mower strikes. I have seen some clearly damaged in this way. The practice is to just leave the clean-out exposed at the surface. One problem is that the clean-outs can get buried and the homeowner can't find it in an emergency.